# Flyway migration fails only on linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, postgresql, flyway

I have this error in my migration script

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException: Migration V1_0_1__initial_schema.sql failed
-------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 458
Location   : db/migration/V1_0_1__initial_schema.sql (/root/server/build/resources/main/db/migration/V1_0_1__initial_schema.sql)
Line       : 50
Statement  : create table xxxxx /* (this is line 50) */
( 
    id               bigserial                 not null primary key,
    name             text                      not null,
    created          timestamptz default now() not null,
    xxxxx_id         uuid                      not null references xxxxx,
    xxxxxx_xx_xxxx   uuid                      not null,
    owner_id         bigint                    not null references "xxxx",
    document         text generated always as ( id::text || ' ' || name ) stored,
    xxxxxx_id bigint references xxxxxx
)
```

but the syntax for the script is fine - works fine locally. Both my local and server machines have postgresql 13 installed

> server

```
# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Debian 13.4-4.pgdg100+1)
```

> local

```
$ "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\psql.exe" --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2
```

Comment: Did you ever work out what the problem was?